# What does "that would be a mistake" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

"The situation is a test of President Donald Trump and his foreign-policy team, including the hawkish national security adviser, John Bolton. This week Mr Bolton hinted at the use of American troops. Barring state violence against American citizens, that would be a mistake."
Does it mean that American forces would only be used against its citizens, otherwise it is illegal?

Comment: The meaning of "mistake" is determined based on the values of the speaker.  He might feel it would be illegal, immoral, politically unpopular, or maybe unprofitable.

Comment: I think a larger sample of this quote is necessary to fully answer this question--it seems likely to me that "that" refers to action mentioned in a previous sentence.

Comment: @Katy I've add some context. It is discussing possible American action toward Venezuelan affairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for editing in the additional context. "That would be a mistake" refers to "use of American troops."

"Barring" means except for or unless something happens. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/barring

In this case, the sentence means "Unless there is violence perpetrated by the Venezuelan state against American citizens, it would be a mistake to use American troops."

A "mistake" doesn't necessarily mean illegal--it simply means the author thinks it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please give us more context, and/or a link to the text where you found the sentence.

I found the [article](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2019/02/02/the-battle-for-venezuelas-future).  I took an extremely brief glance and got the impression that the paragraph that contains your sentence is about whether the US should meddle/intervene in another country or not.  That helped me understand the sentence.  Here's the meaning, loosely:

> Unless violence were perpetrated by the government of the other country against US citizens, intervening/meddling would be a mistake.